# Instalar PHP 7.2 y apache en SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12

Tags: php, linux, apache2

Estoy tratando de instalar PHP 7.2 en SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12, pero me aparece que la última versión compatible es PHP 5. Al intentar forzar la instalación de php 7.2 por rpm me pide actualización de la librería glibc pero no es posible actualizarla.

**Solo puedo realizar la instalación descargando los RPM ya que no cuento con salida a internet**

Answer (score 0):

Segun tengo entendido dado que yo no uso suse, la version 12 incluia soporte para contenedores(Docker), quizas seria mas facil para ti si necesitas "si o si" usar esa version de sistema operativo usar docker para instalar una imagen directamente con la version de php que necesites.

Para cargar imagenes offline en docker lo que puedes es descargar esa imagen en un sistema con acceso a internet y exportarla para luego cargarla en tu sistema Air Gap.

El proceso seria el siguiente:

```
# En el sistema con conexion exterior
docker pull php:7.2-fpm
docker save php > php.tar
xz -9 php.tar

# En tu suse:
docker load < php.tar.xz
```

El fichero quedaria aproximadamente en unos 70Mb

Sobre el uso de la imagen puedes consultar lo siguiente:

https://hub.docker.com/_/php?tab=description